# Running aodv in ns2.34

Tags: ns2

Can someone tell me how to run aodv protocol in ns2.34 .... aodv is already installed in     it ... I have tried command g++ aodv.cc to compile it but it is showing error ??

```
linux@ubuntu :~/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34 $ g++ aodv.cc
    g++: aodv.cc: No such file or directory
    g++: no input files
```

aodv dot cc and aodv dot h files are in folder aodv

Answer (score 2):

In ns2, aodv is like  a back end files. you cannot run aodv.cc files directly. its just a routing protocol you can use tcl script to analyze the aodv operations.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a protocol like this. The protocol is a tool to be used along with other protocols in different OSI layers like MAC protocol etc. Normally a TCL script is written which defines different parameters to be used by the nodes. These parameters indicate the protocols to be used. I suggest you go through the NS manual thoroughly.